# Email variables are allowed only within the context of the session

Tags: informatica

I have created one independent email task after session to generate failure details email. I have provided information for user and status fields But when I'm trying to add email body in text field all built in email variables are disabled.  It says email variables are allowed only within the context of the session.

Can anyone please help me how can I access the email variables in independent email task. I also need to attach session log file with the email.

Appreciate your help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make a dummy mapping and session, you can use built in email variable in that session.

Dummy mapping can have source and target as flatfile (not necessarily having any data).

Answer (score 0):

you can set the configure the email in your actual session it self. in component- post session success/failure.

Comment: This is a common limitation, you can only reference the variables in a post session email command.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `post-session on-failure email` (recommended) or build the message body within the mapping, store it in a variable and use `post-session variable assignment` to use it on workflow level for the email task.